# Redirect example.com users to example.com/#/login

Tags: python, django, redirect

I am working on a project that uses Django and Angular. I do not have a background as a web developer so please try to explain your answer so that a novice person can understand it.

Basically I want to make it so that the login page is the default page instead of the index page.

I currently have the following url handler in my main Django project urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', 'core.views.generic.index')
```

I also have another urls.py in an app called core that sends visitors to the login page:

```
url(r'^/login$', private.MeLogin.as_view())
```

Now I want the login page to become the default page instead if the index page. How can I do that?

I have tried adding the following the the views file in the core app:

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='', login_url='#/login')
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('html/index.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Unfortunately I get the message

> This webpage has a redirect loop

I do not know how to solve this problem. Basically I want users to be redirected to the login page if they enter any URL that is not handled by other URL handlers. When they successfully log in they are redirected to a dashboard page automatically.

**EDIT:**

The login page URL is handled in the core `urls.py` file and points to a different view than index.

```
url(r'^/login$', private.MeLogin.as_view())
```

Comment: The point is that you specify as a login page the same page, and that leads to an infinite redirects.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. The login url points to a separate login page. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Web servers, in this case Django, do not see the fragment after the `#`. You are redirecting from `/` to `/`, creating a redirect loop.

If you want to redirect to the Django login url, you need `login_url='/login'`.

As an aside, you should remove the leading slash from your regex `r'^/login$`.

Comment: When I make those changes and then go to site.com, I get redirected to app.com/login instead of app.com/#/login with the message that "The current URL, login, didn't match any of these.", refering to url handlers.

Comment: The url `/login` shouldn't give you a 404 if you updated the url pattern as well. I'm not familiar with Angular, but it seems like any redirect from `/` to `/#/login` should be handled by Angular, not Django, since the webserver sees them both as the same url.

Answer (score 0):

In `@login_required(redirect_field_name='', login_url='#/login')`
remove `redirect_field_name='',` it really is not neccessary and make sure that `#/login` in `login_url='#/login` is the same as in your url.py file:
like

views.py

`@login_required(redirect_field_name='', login_url='accounts/login/')`

as
url.py

`url(r'^accounts/login/', auth_views.login),`

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Angular & Django apps are running in two seperate ports, like:

- Django on port `8000`
- Angular on port `1000`

So if you give `/#/login` it will redirect for the same with Django port (`8000/#/login`).

So why don't you give the full URL `www.example.com/#/login`?